# Parameter in function with square root in denominator

Tags: calculus

Given the function: $f(x) = \frac{ax+6}{\sqrt{9−x^2}}$

A tangent line is drawn to the function at its intersection point with the $y$-axis (which I solved for and got $(0,2)$). It it known that it is parallel to the line $3y - x = 0$.

Can someone help me just find parameter a?

(1) Parameter a

(2)The maxima and minima

(3) Domain

(4) Places where the function rises and falls

Comment: I think this is not right, it is $$P(0,2)$$

Answer (score 0):

The slope of tangent to the function is given by its derivative at that point. We calculate the derivative of $f(x) = ￼\frac{ax+6}{\sqrt{9-x^2}}$ at $(x,y) = (0,2)$.

$f'(x) = \frac{a(\sqrt{9-x^2})-\frac{1}{\sqrt{9-x^2}}(-2x)(ax+6)}{9-x^2} = \frac{9a-ax^2+2ax^2+12x}{9-x^2} = \frac{ax^2+12x+9a}{9-x^2} $. Hence at $x =0, f'(x) = a$.

Now from the question, we have that the tangent is parallel to the line $y =\frac{1}{3}x$. Therefore the slope must be same for both the line and the tangent and we get $a = \frac{1}{3}.$

Note that for calculating the derivative, I used the quotient formula.